# VisualStudio2019 WebAPI Run from Postman

Tags: postman, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to run the webAPI (C#) in Visual Studio 2019 and test in Postman. These are steps I took

1. Created a new project with type WebAPI in Visual Studio 2019 (selected C#) with example controller (WeatherApp)
2. Ran the application in Visual Studio 2019. It opens the browser and brings up the url as
   http://localhost:62002/weatherforecast
   the application then immediately shutsdown
3. I have postman window open, where I would like to test the api, but I am unable to.

I am trying to setup the environment, so that I can create my new webapi with get/post requests and run from postman, while debugging from visual studio 2019

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I need to run dotnet run from terminal/shell with url https://localhost:5001 and then go to Postman and invoke the service uri. It worked. But not sure how to debug in this mode